# error[E0277]: the trait bound `my_struct::MyStruct: my_trait::MyTrait` is not satisfied

Tags: module, rust, traits

I am writing projects in Rust to help me learn it, but am having trouble implementing a trait and then using a function required by that trait when a type implementing it is passed to a function.

To try and narrow down the problem, I've created an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Here is the error message and code:

**error message**

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `my_struct::MyStruct: my_trait::MyTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:12:5
   |
12 |     invoke_print_i32(&MyStruct { });
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `my_trait::MyTrait` is not implemented for `my_struct::MyStruct`
   |
note: required by `invoke_print_i32`
  --> src\main.rs:7:1
   |
7  | fn invoke_print_i32<T: MyTrait>(instance: &T) {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**my_trait.rs**

```
pub trait MyTrait {
    fn print_i32(&self, n: i32);
}
```

**my_struct.rs**

```
#[path = "my_trait.rs"]
mod my_trait;
use my_trait::MyTrait;

pub struct MyStruct { }

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn print_i32(&self, n: i32) {
        println!("n: {}", n);
    }  
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod my_trait;
use my_trait::MyTrait;

mod my_struct;
use my_struct::MyStruct;

fn invoke_print_i32<T: MyTrait>(instance: &T) {
    instance.print_i32(42);
}

fn main() {
    invoke_print_i32(&MyStruct { });
}
```

My attempts at researching the problem mostly found people trying to implement fairly standard Rust traits, for example:

- [How can I implement Rust's Copy trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35458562/1816262)
- [The trait bound is not satisfied in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39210311/1816262)
- [The trait bound is not satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37779313/1816262)

I also read somewhere that I needed to reimplement the trait for variables such as `&MyStruct`, but my attempts to do so didn't resolve the issue.

**extra info**

- `rustc -V` outputs `rustc 1.36.0 (a53f9df32 2019-07-03)`
- `cargo -V` outputs `cargo 1.36.0 (c4fcfb725 2019-05-15)`
- Platform/OS is Windows 10 Pro (x86_64)

**question**

What am I doing wrong; how can I correctly implement the trait?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use one module from another module in a Rust cargo project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071513/how-to-use-one-module-from-another-module-in-a-rust-cargo-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared the module `my_trait` twice, so there are actually two different traits called `MyTrait`: `crate::my_trait` and `crate::my_struct::my_trait`.

You don't need to declare the module in the `my_struct` module. Instead, use the module that is declared in the crate root, with:

```
use crate::my_trait::MyTrait;
```

Or

```
use super::my_trait::MyTrait;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this had been driving me mad for hours!